# How to use debugger statements in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, debugging

I have a Node.js project and I would like to know how to use 'debugger;' statements to pause execution and check the stack trace, and variables status in Chrome.

This works in one of my other projects that uses React JS, Node and Express.

Currently the issue is that debugger statements are ignored and the app continues running without stopping. Is there a configuration or library that should be installed to enable the functionality?

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --inspect ./bin/www",
    "debug-app": "node --inspect --debug-brk ./bin/www",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bull": "^3.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "ioredis": "^4.5.1",
    "mongo-express": "^0.51.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.3",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@types/bull": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

**bin/www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
require('babel-register')({
  presets: ['env']
});
require("@babel/polyfill");

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('mean-app:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val)
{
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port))
  {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0)
  {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error)
{
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen')
  {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code)
  {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening()
{
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: Read this [Debugging Guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).  If you have Chrome you can use its built in inspector.  And please confirm that you are running your app with `npm run debug-app`.

Comment: Thank you! :) It works after adding 
"chrome-devtools-frontend" and opening the inspector in Chrome via: chrome://inspect/#devices -> Open dedicated DevTools for Node